# FindElements returns 0 event Text property has value

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to go through cells in a table

```
 var rows = d.FindElementsByXPath(@"//table[@id='table2']/tbody/tr");

 foreach (IWebElement r in rows)
 {
      var cells = r.FindElements(By.Name("td"));
 }
```

The cells collection is empty even I see text values from the cells in the row Text property. Am I missing something ? I see the cells also in the browser. I'm using ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`By.Name` is looking for `name` attribute, for example

```
<a id="id" name="name">
```

Uses:

```
FindElements(By.Name("name"));
```

To locate tag use `By.TagName`

```
var cells = r.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
```